# Selecing an overloaded method using 'Named arguments'

Tags: c#

I want to use 'Named Arguments' feature as parameter.

There is two methods.

```
Class temp {
    public method(Class1 param);
    public method(Class2 param);
};
```

In case of above class, if I want to call method using 'named arguments'. I can call like `method(param: 'some value');` and I want to give `null` in 'some value', so when I try like this,

```
method(param:null);
```

I see this message

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'method' and 'method'

Then, I realized these two (Class1, Class2) are very similar.

So when I try to cast it like this,

```
method((Class1)param:null);
```

I failed with message below.

> The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context

So can 'cast' this 'param' parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't try what's literally the only other option to arrange these identifiers? Preparing for 10 answers all saying the same in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Guilty...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh i see. I'll try to find more next time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
MethodName(param: (Class1)null)
```

Basically, you need to cast the `null` to your given type, not the parameter

Comment: Thank you so much :) i got it!

Answer (score 0):

Why not seperate the two methods?

- method1(Class1 param)
- method2(Class2 param)

OR something like:

```
public method<T>(T param)
{
    if(param.GetType() == typeof(Class1))
    {
      //Do stuff for Class1
      Console.WriteLine("Class1");
    }
    else if (param.GetType() == typeof(Class2))
    {
      //Do stuff for Class2
      Console.WriteLine("Class2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am on making unit test about this class and  What i want is about using 'named arguments' when input value in specific method. And this class is not mine. So i don't know why these two are seperated..  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: That is a horrible use of generics